# error gyp, node self-signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: node.js, npm, gyp

Good day. I have the problem.

```
gyp ERR! stack FetchError: request to https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.0.0/node-v18.0.0-headers.tar.gz failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ASerobabov\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.0.0\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:539:35)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
gyp ERR! stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

How do solve this problem?

I tried npm config set strict-ssl false

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.